# ContainerView it not located correct

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipagecontrol, uicontainerview

I have a setup where I use a Navigation controller which includes a container view which embeds a page view controller and its content.

[image]
*From the left: UINavigationController, my class MTNewsViewController inheriting from UIViewController and implements UIPageViewControllerDataSource (holding a container view), UIPageViewController, my class MTNewsContentController which inherits from UIViewController.*

I have managed to insert a number of pages into the page controller with custom text and image. But, **the problem is the position and size of the container view**. It is not positioned as the image storyboard suggests but from the top left corner and with another size. Like this:

[image]

I am not sure about what is missing.

Here are some code snippets. Do you have any suggestions on what could be wrong? I am suspecting that I need to set the size somewhere.

**MTNewViewController**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Create page view controller
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;

    [self loadNews];

    MTNewsContentController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

    [self addChildViewController:_pageViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:_pageViewController.view];
    [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    UIPageControl* pageControlDots = [UIPageControl appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[MTNewsViewController class]]];
    pageControlDots.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    pageControlDots.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    pageControlDots.hidesForSinglePage = YES;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    self.pageViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    self.pageViewController.view.frame = segue.destinationViewController.view.frame;
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = [self getCurrentPageIndex:viewController];

    if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound)) {
        return nil;
    }

    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:--index];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = [self getCurrentPageIndex:viewController];

    if (index == NSNotFound) {
        return nil;
    }

    if (++index == news.size()) {
        return nil;
    }

    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (MTNewsContentController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    if ((news.size() == 0) || (index >= news.size())) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
    MTNewsContentController *newPage = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NewsPageContentController"];
    newPage.imagePath = [NSString stringWithCString:news[index].kImagePath.c_str() encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    newPage.textDescription = [NSString stringWithCString:news[index].kDescription.c_str() encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    newPage.pageIndex = index;

    return newPage;
}

- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return news.size();
}

- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return 0;
}

- (NSUInteger)getCurrentPageIndex:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    return ((MTNewsContentController*) viewController).pageIndex;
}
```

**MTNewsContentController**

Nothing special here. Just adding an image and some text programatically.

**ContainerView constraints**

[image]

Comment: Hard to say without the project as the images doesn't show the true layout during runtime. Are you using Storyboards? How do you manage layout? (Autolayout, Spings & Struts, ..)

Comment: Yes, I am using storyboards. But not sure about your second question?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's most likely that you have not put layout constraints on your container view.
As a result, it may not appear in the same way at runtime as in your storyboard.
That container view must be constrained both horizontally and vertically.
You could select the container view, then drag it to its parent view while holding the Ctrl key.
Then a constraints menu will pop up.
Hold the shift key and select the top four options which are leading and trailing space to safe area, and top and bottom space to safe area. Make sure to have a tick besides each of them. And then try running your app again.

Comment: As this is the same suggestion I have the same answer :)
They are already added. I have added an image of them.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you are setting some auto layout constraints anywhere. Open storyboards -> select your container view -> Select the layout option highlighted on the image [image] -> set top, left, right and bottom constraints as per your requirements and click add/save. This should be all you need.

Comment: I just double checked. They have already been set. I have added an image of the constraints for the ContainerView.